# how to smoothly move object on accelerometer value change

Tags: android, iphone, windows-phone-7, windows-8, monogame

I was writing a game were I am moving object. I want to object to move very smoothly, like even small change in accelerometer should update position of object.

Now how to deal with accelerometer noise? That is accelerometer event will keep firing even I will not move device.

I have browsed for it but could not found any good solution.

I have also tried solution like setting threshold, or keep a last updated value and if change then update position etc. But these will not help in smooth movement.

Games on iphone and android does this. Object moves very smoothly.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use a threshold around 0 (or the value you get when not moving), and then when overcoming it you modify the speed vector of your object according to the inclination of your device, this will create smoothly movements.